# Why does the app crash on launch when trying to insert String from array into TextView?

Tags: android

So, I'm just trying to have an array with a couple of values, and have a textview "fill" with the one I specify upon pressing a button.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String arr[]={"a","b","c","d","e"};

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

private void setLaunchBtn() {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText(arr[2]);
        }
    });
}
```

For some reason I can't get the app to launch at all, even if I try `tv.setText("inserttext");`

Comment: share your error log and initialize the TextView inside the on create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can't find a view in the View declaration, you gotta find the views after setContentView() method, just like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String arr[]={"a","b","c","d","e"};

TextView tv; // Remove findViewById

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv); // Try with this
    tv.setText("Hello");
    setLaunchBtn(); // You need to call this method to execute it
}

private void setLaunchBtn() {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tv.setText(arr[2]);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: The app is launching now, but the button doesn't seem to do anything, with both the array and plain text.

Comment: Please check my code again, i added setLaunchBtn(); in onCreate method

Comment: Of course... I don't know how I missed that even. Thanks so much for taking the time to help a rookie :)